# Command in variable one are affecting output of other variable when displayed together in UNIX

Tags: bash, awk, echo, cut

I am having two file naming Extra_info and Class_info

Class_info contains data :

```
stuId stuName stuClass 
S01    Josh  First
S02    harsh    First
S03    Roop     Second
S04    Kali     Third
```

Extra_info contains extra information about student like

```
stuId stuCity stuEmail         stuPhone
S01    Poh  faltu@gmail.com  1234567890
```

I am getting result from both files using grep for stuId and displaying the result as:

```
res1=`grep $stuId $locDir/Class_info`
res2=`grep $stuId $locDir/Extra_info|cut -d" " -f2-` 
## also I tried res2=`grep $stuId $locDir/Extra_info|awk '{$1="" ; print $0}'`
echo $res1 $res2
```

Instead of displaying:

```
     S01 jagdeep First Sirsa  faltu@gmail.com  1234567890
```

It is displaying:

```
     Sirsa  faltu@gmail.com  1234567890
```

As I could think at the time of echo the variable res2 is nullifying result from res1.

Please, suggest the possible reason for this and please provide solution for the same.

Comment: Works as expected for me. Have you checked if $res1 is getting correct output without print $res2?

Comment: Very strange. I tried under `zsh`, same result: if I store the result of 2 consecutive `grep` in two variables and `echo` them, the first is not printed. If I only `echo` the first, it works. If the first is assigned the result of a `ls` instead of a `grep`, it works. So the problem could be related to `grep` outputs? I don't understand why.

Comment: @JPG I can confirm that it works under `zsh` on my system as expected, ie. the results of both `grep`s are printed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your input files probably have CR-NL line endings, so $res1 returns the cursor to the beginning of the line then then $res2 overwrites it. Run your files through `dos2unix` to fix that.

Comment: Yes, you got it! I am also working with a file with CR-NL, that's the reason. If I remove them, it works.

Comment: @glenn: Thanks for replying , I copied the sample content in new files and it worked. But the data is large so I have to work with same files.
tried to find the suspicious extra character in the file, unable to find . Is there any command which could  help to find out the culprit character

Comment: `od -c filename` will display the `\r` prior to the `\n`

Comment: @glennjackman : Thanks , I am able to find the character and replaced using tr command, It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
s=`grep jagdeep file1.txt |awk '{print $1}'`
egrep $s file2.txt
```